# ADVICE NEEDED: Real Time responsive Pub/Sub pattern for ASP.NET Core Razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, responsive-design, publish-subscribe

I am mandated to research on the pub/sub pattern to enable real time alerts for a Micro-Service architecture and trying to get it to work on docker using redis and .net core razor pages 7.0

HISTORY
Prior to this, we were using signalR, in .net FRAMEWORK, but now redesigning the entire application in .net core and moving away from a single dependency

OBJECTIVES
We want to use Redis and the default InMemoryCacheServices as our temp database, and a mixture of Redis pub/sub, Kafka, RabbitMQ.

WHAT I HAVE ARCHIVED
I have redis running on docker locally and can send realtime messages via console apps with the code below.

MY QUESTIONS

1. Does anyone know how this works ? ie make the front end responsive ?
2. The onGet() method below returns the value in the console app, but a boolean in the razor page
3. Or if I am going down the wrong direction, can anyone point me into the necessary patterns and technologies to be implemented ?

thank you

```
// ................... PROGRAM.CS In .net 7.0  ....................................//


var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configurationOptions);
ISubscriber subScriber = redis.GetSubscriber();
builder.Services.AddScoped(s => redis.GetDatabase());

// ................... CONSTRUCTOR ....................................//

        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
         private readonly IDatabase _database;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger,IDatabase database)//, ISubscriber isubscribe)
        {
            _database = database;
            _logger = logger;
           } 

// ................... OnGet method ....................................//

public void OnGet()
        {
            var configurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
            {
                EndPoints = { { "localhost", 32768 } },
                AbortOnConnectFail = false,     ,
                ConnectTimeout = 10000
            };

// I had manually hard coded the Redis connection to step through the code to see the returning values

           var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configurationOptions);
            ISubscriber subScriber = redis.GetSubscriber();
 
           var pubSub = redis.GetSubscriber();

            ViewData["message"] = pubSub.SubscribeAsync("MyKey", (channel, message) => MessageAction(message));
           ViewData["message2"] = _database.StringGetAsync("MyKey").ToString();
      
        }

        private void MessageAction(RedisValue message)
        {
            ViewData["message3"] = message;

        }
```

1. I have tried the above code
2. I am expecting to get a responsive UI in .net core razor pages

Comment: as far as I know Razor pages do not have live updates. What you probably want is Blazor.

Comment: No we dont want to use blazor or be tied down to any one technology. Thanks @lordvlad30

Comment: What do you even mean with tied down to one technology. You are currently tied down to Razor Pages ...

Comment: If we use blazor or SignalR, then our other front end clients e.g. Mobile devices, WPF and other IoT devices are left out.

Comment: And with Razor Pages not? On each of those devices you can browse to a website. Blazor components can even be used in a WPF application